# How can I make Automapper set a reference to the source object in the destination object?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

In the application I am busy writing, all my mapping destination objects derive from a base class like this:

```
public class CatalogObject<TObject>
{
    TObject InnerObject { get; set; }
}

public class CatalogTable : CatalogObject<table>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

Now, after mapping a `table` object to a `CatalogTable` object, I want the `InnerObject` property of that destination to be a reference to the source `table` object.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a [Custom Resolver](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers):

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Table, CatalogTable>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.InnerObject,
               opt => opt.ResolveUsing<InnerObjectResolver>());
```

Where the resolver would look something like:

```cs
public class InnerObjectResolver : ValueResolver<Table, Table>
{
    protected override Table ResolveCore(Table source)
    {
        return source;
    }
```

}

Full details can be found in the [custom resolver documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers).

You might also be able to do it directly, but I haven't tried that. Something like this maybe:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.InnerObject, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
```

Comment: Your resolver won't compile. It can't return `source`, of type `Source`, because it's declared return type is `Table`.

Comment: Correct. It wasn't the actual code you should use, but simply an example of how you might be able to use it. The link I provided will give full details of how to implement a custom resolver. However if the last example works, that might be the easier solution to implement. Again, it might not compile, it is simply an example. I can provide a working solution if you can add some unit tests that you want to see passing.

Comment: And yeah, that code was dumb. I've updated the answer to hopefully reflect what you want a little better. Again - still untested.

Comment: That last snippet totally works... at least in my initial test. Awesome!